# PHPmyadmin INNoDB Restore

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, innodb

Please i need a quick support/help.

I came to the office this morning, and i could not start apache, i found out that some files were missing. SO i decided to unistall xampp and reinstall it. However, i already backed up "mysql" folder and httdocs folder.

Now when i finished the new installation, i restored the mysql/data folder to the new installation mysql director.

Now the database for my project has MYIsam and INNoDB  tables. When i lunched phpmyadmin, i could only see the MYIsam tables but the INNoDB tables didnt display.

Please can anybody help me on how to show those tables with INNodb..

AM working on a big project and i cant afford to loss my database.